# calculate average + sd with multiple conditions and NA values

Tags: r, average, multiple-columns, na, multiple-conditions

I am trying to calculate the average and sd of several numeric columns (with NA values) based on three character conditions:

average + sd for (f1,f2,f3,f4) grouped as:

```
-ps S0/hepatopancreas/sporulated-no
-ps S1/hepatopancreas/sporulated-no
-ps S2/hepatopancreas/sporulated-no
-ps S3/hepatopancreas/sporulated-no
-ps S4/hepatopancreas/sporulated-no
-ps S3& S4/hepatopancreas/sporulated (combined ps)
-spores
```

## questions

-what happens with the NA values?

-Is it possible to simultaneously calculate the (average +sd) of the four columns (f1,f2,f3,f4)?

-How should I combine ps S3 and ps s4 (hepatopancreas/sporulated)?

```
set.seed(02082022)
#generate random dataset
size<-runif(14, min=20, max=40)
ps<-c("S0","S3", "S2", "S0", "S1","S1", "S4", "S3","S3", "S1", "S2", "S4" ,"S3", "S3")
bc<-sample(x = c("pos", "neg"),size = 14, replace = TRUE) 
sex<-sample(x = c("Female", "Male"),size = 14, replace = TRUE) 
f1<-runif(14, min=0.2, max=15)
f2<- c(1,NA,2,3,NA,5,6,NA,8,5,8,10,7,8)
f2<-c(NA,2,8,6,NA,5,8,10,3,3,4,5,4,6) 
f3<-c(2,4,5,9,8,5,6,7,NA,5,10, NA,12,15)
f4<-runif(14, min=0.2, max=10)
sporulated<-c("no","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","yes")
tissue<-c("hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas",
          "hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas",
          "hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas","hepatopancreas",
          "spore","spore")

df <- data.frame(sex,ps,bc,size,  sporulated, tissue,f1, f2,f3,f4)
print(df)


# my attempts

x<-df$f1
f1<-do.call(data.frame, aggregate(f1~  sporulated+ps+tissue,data = df, 
                                        function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))
colnames(f1) <- c("sporulated","ps","tissue", "f1_mean", "f1_sd")
print(f1)     


x<-df$f2
f2<-do.call(data.frame, aggregate(f2~  sporulated+ps+tissue,data = df, 
                                        function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))
colnames(f2) <- c("sporulated","ps","tissue", "f2_mean", "f2_sd")
print(f2)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can add an na.rm=T in your mean() function and sd() function I believe. This will remove all NA's from your calculation. If you do ?mean() you can see the argument in the help file. Note that if you do `mean(c(3,4,NA))` it will return NA, but if you add the extra argument `na.rm = T` it will return 3.5

Comment: describe() which is in the psych package (must have Rtools installed first to install package) does all you want in one go along with much else.

Answer (score 0):

another option (problem with NA values remains...)

```
 df %>%
 group_by(tissue, ps,sporulated,na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  filter(tissue == "hepatopancreas",na.rm = TRUE)%>%
  get_summary_stats(f1,f2,f3,f4, type = "mean_sd")%>%
  print(n=40)
```

Comment: Greetings! This isn't really an answer more than it is follow up to your original question. Its better to just edit this into your question next time.